# How do I get the Hadoop input filename from mapper?

Tags: ruby, hadoop, mapper

Hadoop streaming makes the filename available to every map task through the environment variable.

Python:

```
os.environ["map.input.file"]
```

Java:

```
System.getenv(“map.input.file”).
```

How about Ruby?

```
mapper.rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

STDIN.each_line do |line|
  line.split.each do |word|
    word = word[/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/] 
    word = word.gsub(/ /,"")
    puts [word, 1].join("\t")
  end
end

puts ENV['map.input.file']
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
ENV['map.input.file']
```

Ruby lets you assign to the ENV hash just as easily:

```
ENV['map.input.file'] = '/path/to/file'
```

Comment: Will it work locally if I do $ cat text.txt | ruby  mapper.rb | sort | ruby reducer.rb

Comment: Why not try it and see. Ruby's use of `ENV` is built-into the language. If "map.input.file" is set in the environment it'd be an easy thing to test. `cat text.txt | ruby mapper.rb | sort | ruby reducer.rb` is a workflow that should be written all in one Ruby script though.

Comment: I can't help you. You haven't showed any source code, plus that would be off-topic for this question.

Comment: upd. with my mapper. just need to understand how to get input filename for mapper and test it locally first

Comment: I rejected your edit attempt for my answer. You are free to edit your own question all you want, however do NOT edit other people's code. Spelling and grammar correction are fine, but your edit would have been rejected by the general populace. Stack Overflow isn't a BBS, it's a Q&A site, so modify your question by appending your code to the bottom of it.

Comment: so, got it. will not work locally unless the var is manually set. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

All JobConf variables are put into environment variables by hadoop-streaming. The variable names are made "safe" by converting any character not in `0-9 A-Z a-z` to `_`.

So map.input.file => map_input_file

Try: `puts ENV['map_input_file']`

Answer (score 0):

Using the input from op, I tried mapper:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
file_name = os.getenv('map_input_file')
print file_name
```

and a standard  wordcount reducer using command:

```
hadoop fs -rmr /user/itsjeevs/wc && 
hadoop jar $STRMJAR  -files /home/jejoseph/wc_mapper.py,/home/jejoseph/wc_reducer.py \
    -mapper wc_mapper.py  \
    -reducer wc_reducer.py \
    -numReduceTasks 10  \
    -input "/data/*"  \
    -output wc
```

to fail with error:

```
 16/03/10 15:21:32 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1455931799889_822384_m_000043_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:434)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.io.TextInputWriter.writeUTF8(TextInputWriter.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.io.TextInputWriter.writeValue(TextInputWriter.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.map(PipeMapper.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

16/03/10 15:21:32 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1455931799889_822384_m_000077_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:345)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.io.TextInputWriter.writeUTF8(TextInputWriter.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.io.TextInputWriter.writeValue(TextInputWriter.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.map(PipeMapper.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

Not sure what is happening.